# .then() on node modules not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, module

I'm working on a react native app right now and I wrote my own module to store some information separated from my components.

While I did that I noticed that in my module I created, I had a function like this:

```
testFetch = function(url){
return fetch(url);
}

exports.test = testFetch;
```

In my main module I did the following:

```
import ts from 'test-module'

ts.test("http://example.com").then((response) => {console.log(response)});
```

But .then() is not getting fired for any reason. The request went through and was successful.

Any help on this?

Comment: Please confirm that misnaming in the example doesn't come from real life  (and please correct that).

Comment: Add a `catch` handler. You probably have an error, and since there's no `catch`, it's being ignored.

Comment: In `exports.test = testFetch`, you don't show where `testFetch` is defined and then when you import it, you try to use `ts.testFetch()` instead of `ts.test()`.  Your naming and use of the names is all goofed up.

Comment: Okay my bad, sorry I corrected it. Of course the problem still occurs and doesn't change anything

Comment: Even after your edit, you are still calling `ts.testFetch()`, but the symbol you exported is `ts.test()`.  Please take care in writing an accurate question.

Comment: I agree with Kryten.  Anytime you wonder why `.then()` isn't getting called, add a `.catch()` to see if there's an error being throw.  Well, actually, you should ALWAYS have a `.catch()` handler.

Comment: @jfriend00 I saw that, thanks for noticing again.

Comment: Adding a catch into this will throw me the following:

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_test-module2.default.test("http://example.com").then(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you mix CommonJS and ES6 modules. You seem to expect that `ts` in your example main module gives you the value of the whole `export` in your module dependency, but that's not how it works.

You can use `export default` to export your `testFetch` function, like so:

```
testFetch = function (url) {
    return fetch(url);
}

export default testFetch;
```

Main module:

```
import testFetch from 'test-module';

testFetch("http://example.com").then((response) => {console.log(response)});
```